# Check built-in function in php

Tags: php, function, native, built-in

I want to verify if a string value has the name of a built-in function in php. There is some way of know it?

I've used function_exists function but I only to use call_user_func_array in non buit-in functions.

Thanks

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried, or why you think `function_exists` will not work.

Comment: function_exists will check if there is a function with that name. But I want to filter with php functions and my own functions

Comment: Ahhh... so some random input string, you wanted to discern if someone is trying to hijack using a built-in function name, rather than a function you defined and allowed. You could also get away with check against a whitelist for only your allowed functions that the string would call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [get_defined_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php)

```
<?php

$b = get_defined_functions();
in_array('something', $b['internal']); //FALSE
in_array('in_array', $b['internal']); //TRUE
```

The function `function_exists` will return true for both built-in and user-defined, with this code you can check only with built-in functions;

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem @Luis , if it works for you please mark as accepted to help others with the same issue

Comment: Right, important part is the `internal` check only. I need more coffee.